# In Table view List it's Only Retrieving the Files that I had created

Tags: google-drive-api, xcode4.6

When I am using the sample code for iOS, in Table view List it's only retrieving the files that I had created.

I want To see all files I'm creating through App and already created on Google Drive.

Where should I make a change? Also, I am not even able to open panel to upload file.

I am using Xcode 4.6

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have access to the complete drive you need to request the full Drive scope, not just the Drive.file scope. Please read the documentation on [choosing the correct scope for the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes). If you look at the [Google Drive iOS authorization documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/ios), you can change the `scopes` variable.

```
NSString scopes = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply.I am new in iPhone development. I follow that procedure but i got number of errors during this and when i got error i deleted that line of code and i used same drEdit and this is not fetching all drive files.Can you please help me to solve this problem. I'll understand only via code. so, can you please send me working project .

Comment: Thank you very much ali :) .I did one mistake and thats why scope was not working.